# Get certificates from user's local computer

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, x509certificate, syncfusion

Using syncfusion, this part of code can get certificates from local machine.

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;

After deployment to server, app is reading certificates from server computer, not USER'S.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`X509Store` uses windows certificates manager to store/retrieve certificates. `CurrentUser` means current OS **user, that server is running on**. `LocalMachine` would mean system-wide certificate (across all server OS users).

It has nothing to do with the connected user to the server.